# WSO2 DATA SERVICES Nested Querys. How can i

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-data-services-server

we have three querys, one select and two insert queries. 
We have to execute the select query and it returns a row with four fields.
Then we have to use these four fields to excute the inserts querys.
Select query works fine, but when WSO2 ESB try to execute the next nested query fails, and show the next error

```
Unable to sendViaPost to url[http://6f478fba7fca:8280/services/...........SOAP12Endpoint] {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender
```

This is the xml about our data service.

```
<query id="updateASMCRRN" useConfig="DATABASE1_PRE">
      <sql>UPDATE BOSA_ASMCRRCN SET RT_COD=:RT_COD, SET RT_DATE_DAT=to_date(:RT_DATE_DAT,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'), WHERE SUMMON_COD=:SUMMON_COD AND SUMREQ_SEQTMP=:SUMREQ_SEQTMP</sql>
      <param name="RT_COD" sqlType="STRING"/>
      <param name="RT_DATE_DAT" sqlType="STRING"/>
      <param name="SUMMON_COD" sqlType="STRING"/>
      <param name="SUMREQ_SEQTMP" sqlType="INTEGER"/>
   </query>
```

......

```
<query id="selectNewSol" useConfig="DATABASE2_PRE">
      <sql>SELECT  s.NUMEROREGISTRO, to_char(s.FECHA,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') AS FECHA, v1.C_CLAVE_ID, v1.A_VALOR AS SUMMON_COD, v2.C_CLAVE_ID, v2.A_VALOR AS SUMREQ_SEQTMP FROM  adel.ae_solicitudes s, adel.ae_valores v1, adel.ae_valores v2 WHERE s.CODFORMULARIO='1057' AND s.B_PROCESADA=1  AND s.NUMEROREGISTRO = v1.NUMEROREGISTRO   AND v1.C_CLAVE_ID='.SUMMON_COD' AND s.NUMEROREGISTRO = v2.NUMEROREGISTRO  AND v2.C_CLAVE_ID='.SUMREQ_SEQTMP'</sql>
      <sql dialect="oracle">SELECT  s.NUMEROREGISTRO, to_char(s.FECHA,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') AS FECHA, v1.C_CLAVE_ID, v1.A_VALOR AS SUMMON_COD, v2.C_CLAVE_ID, v2.A_VALOR AS SUMREQ_SEQTMP FROM  adel.ae_solicitudes s, adel.ae_valores v1, adel.ae_valores v2 WHERE s.CODFORMULARIO='1057' AND  s.B_PROCESADA=1 AND s.NUMEROREGISTRO = v1.NUMEROREGISTRO  AND v1.C_CLAVE_ID='.SUMMON_COD' AND s.NUMEROREGISTRO = v2.NUMEROREGISTRO AND v2.C_CLAVE_ID='.SUMREQ_SEQTMP'</sql>
      <result element="Solicitudes" rowName="Solicitud">
         <element export="SUMMON_COD" name="SUMMON_COD" query-param="SUMMON_COD" xsdType="string"/>
         <element export="RT_COD" name="RT_COD" query-param="NUMEROREGISTRO" xsdType="string"/>
         <element export="RT_DATE_DAT" name="RT_DATE_DAT" query-param="FECHA" xsdType="string"/>
         <element export="SUMREQ_SEQTMP" name="SUMREQ_SEQTMP" query-param="SUMREQ_SEQTMP" xsdType="integer"/>
         <call-query href="updateASMCRRN">
            <with-param name="RT_COD" query-param="NUMEROREGISTRO"/>
            <with-param name="RT_DATE_DAT" query-param="FECHA"/>
            <with-param name="SUMMON_COD" query-param="SUMMON_COD"/>
            <with-param name="SUMREQ_SEQTMP" query-param="SUMREQ_SEQTMP"/>
         </call-query>
      </result>
   </query>
   <operation name="selectNewSol">
      <call-query href="selectNewSol"/>
   </operation>
```

Now this is the error:

```
 ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender} -  Failed to submit the response {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender}
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processPostNormalQuery': DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processPostNormalQuery': operation not allowed
DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Nested Exception:-
java.sql.SQLException: operation not allowed

DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: pollingSolicitudesADEL
Location: /pollingSolicitudesADEL.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: selectNewSol
Current Params: {}
Nested Exception:-
DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processPostNormalQuery': operation not allowed
DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Nested Exception:-
java.sql.SQLException: operation not allowed


        at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter.writeTo
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Could you post the exception from the WSO2DSS (log and the reply)?

Comment: And - you have an error in the update SQL statement (a comma before `WHERE`)

Comment: ok....I haven't seen...what a newbie error. I've modified the stament and it shows another error. I'll modified the answer with the new error.

Comment: I have bad feeling that you may have only `select` in the nested query (even when you have insert/update in the top query, the nested statement is not invoked). I'd advice to expose both queries (one select one update) and call each of it from the client ..

Comment: we have no clients that they call each of it. We have to setup a scheduled task which calls each of operation .

Comment: do you have skype to talk about it?